# Minecraft: sweepAttack particles upon attack with a diamond sword and detect direction

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need some help with a cool command I'm trying to make using either 1 or multiple command blocks in 1.10. I'm trying to activate the `sweepAttack` particle based on the direction the player is facing upon an attack to an entity. Not only that, I'd like to make the attack look and act like a barrage of attacks hence the usage of the `sweepAttack` particle. So to sum up what I'm trying to make is: whenever a player attacks an entity there will be 5 individual attacks with 1 swing of a sword or any other thing in your hand along with the `sweepAttack` particle based off of the direction the player is facing to add a bit of realism to it. Can you help me make this possible in-game?

Answer (score 1):

I have been unable to find a way to get it to work in 1.10.X

A solution is to use 1.13.X where they have introduced the new relative notation - the caret (^)

First, set up a scoreboard looking at minecraft.used:minecraft.diamond_sword

```
/scoreboard objectives add Sword minecraft.used:minecraft.diamond_sword
```

Next,

```
/execute if score @p Sword matches 1 run execute as @a at @s anchored eyes run particle minecraft:sweep_attack ^ ^ ^2 0 0 0 0.01 20 force
```

This looks for if the player has used a sword

Next go all of the particle command blocks (in your case, 5)

All command blocks to be chain, and conditional

```
/execute at @a[scores={Sword=1}] run particle minecraft:sweep_attack ^ ^ ^2 0 0 0 0.01 20 force
```

At the end, the last conditional chain command block

```
scoreboard players set @a Sword 0
```

[image: cmdblock setup]